# Issue while trying to update to SDK tools 26.1.1

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

Was trying to update SDK tools in android studio to 26.1.1, but I keep getting this error and have to cancel, what can i do about it please?

[image: Issue]

Answer (score 0):

**The solutions is to uninstall the android sdk tools**, ...because you tried to install the update before and your internet disconnected..and make files conflict.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9X7Xb54VfoM
give me point if this works.
and i wish the answer accepted.
.
.
.
and download successfully

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSRa4.jpg)